# How to create list item scroll-able in Recycler View?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, horizontal-scrolling

I have created Recycler View. Everything is working fine. I want my List Item to expand and not wrap content according to screen. It should be Horizontally scrollable list Item.

My Recycler View XML:

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/recyclerView2"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

And this is my code to set up Recyler View.

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());


    recyclerView2.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager2);
    recyclerView2.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you change recycler view height like below..

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
  android:id="@+id/recyclerView2"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Comment: Yeah, this isn't what they're asking. They're talking about horizontally scrollable items.

Comment: then recycler view set scroll view like mLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);

Comment: No, the items horizontally scrolling individually, not the whole `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Sorry sir but mLayoutManager dont have any method with "setOrientation" .

Comment: used this things         recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL,false);

Comment: HorizontalScrollView helped me. I have added HorizontalScrollView over list Item layout and it gives me the desired result. Will try yours answer too.

Comment: This not seems working at my end . 
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL,false);

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood you need a recycler view which scroll vertically and each item in the recyclerview needs to scroll horizontally.
For that you need each item of your recycler view to be a recycler view in and of itself.There are tutorials online, you can take a look at this [Google Play Store Replica](https://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/12/horizontal-recyclerview-in-vertical.html)

Comment: Sorry sir but mLayoutManager dont have any method with "setOrientation"

Comment: @ArmanReyaz I have edited my answer, please check out the link and let me know if that is what you were looking for.

Comment: @ArmanReyaz If that was what you are looking for a simple google search for `android horizontal scroll in vertical recycler view` should give you more than enough content to create the list that you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help Sir but HorizontalScrollView helped me. I have added HorizontalScrollView  over list Item layout and it gives me the desired result.

Comment: if you try to recyler view inside item that scroll in horizontal way that time you need do define scrollview in adapter layout that bind into a recycler view.